# ajax json playframwork parser can not get correspond value

Tags: ajax, json, scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

My framework is playframework2.2.2.
I use the jquery to send ajax json:
my javascript(client) part:

```
$("#newapply" ).click(function(){
  var htmlrespone=$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : ' @routes.CommonController.postdata ',
    data : JSON.stringify({"userid": "111233456"}),
    sucess:function(){
      $("#newapply" ).html("already apply");
      $("#newapply" ).prop("enable",false);
    },
    contentType: 'appliction/json'
  });
})
```

my post string from my firebug is:

```
{"userid":"111233456"}
```

my server part received the post is:

```
def postdata = Action { request =>
  val body: AnyContent = request.body
  val textBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson   //here I always get None I donot know why
  textBody.map{json=>
    Ok("Got:"+(json\"userid").as[String])
  }.getOrElse{
    BadRequest("Expecting text/plain request body")
  }
}
```

Here I always get the BadRequest as the getOrElse statement is alway None.
I think the post should be json object or JsValue.
but why here I get None? How to get the JsValue from body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application/json is misspelled. Having the field `contentType: 'application/json'` should be all that's needed to send json request.

Answer (score 1):

i think, you can't simply pass the request body data in ajax data.

In ajax data,just pass the variable with value,like this

```
var reqData=JSON.stringify({"userid": "111233456"})
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : ' @routes.CommonController.postdata() ', //add proper function brackets after postdata
    data : {"data",reqData},
    sucess:function(){
      $("#newapply" ).html("already apply");
      $("#newapply" ).prop("enable",false);
    }
  });
```

(sorry, i know only java not scala)

In routes file,just add like this

```
 controllers.CommonController.postdata(data: String ?="")
```

and in your controller,just do like this

```
 public static Result postdata (String data) {
  //do your stuff
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Sorry, I want to pass with json format data, your answer is just pass the application/form-url-encoded: Map[String, Seq[String]] formated data. and the body received as form instead of real json.

Comment: that's ok. just pass the json data as string and in controller,get the string and parse it to the json. i hope,you know how to parse json string to json object.